# Flex: Create custom stroke on LineSeries?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts, alpha, stroke

You can easily set a stroke on a line series like this:

```
<mx:LineSeries yField="apple">
    <mx:lineStroke>
        <mx:Stroke 
                    color="0x6699FF" 
                    weight="4" 
                    alpha=".8"
        />
    </mx:lineStroke>
</mx:LineSeries>
```

This will set alpha for the entire stroke to .8

But I want to be able to set a different alpha on the stoke for each plot based on something in the dataProvider.

For example the `yField` in the lineSeries is "Apple" which is how it knows where to plot for the lineSeries. I want to be able to add something like `alphaField` which tells it what to set the stroke alpha for each plot.

so if my dataProvider was:

```
<result month="Jan-04">
    <apple>81768</apple>
    <alpha>1</alpha>
</result>
<result month="Feb-04">
    <apple>51156</apple>
    <alpha>1</alpha>
</result>
<result month="Mar-04">
    <apple>51156</apple>
    <alpha>.5</alpha>
</result>
```

And I set `alphaField="alpha"` then I would have a solid stroke from plot 0 to plot 1 and then a 50% alpha stroke from plot 1 to plot 2.

How can I do this??? I am looking in the commitProperties() and updateDisplayList() methods of LineSeries and have no idea what would need to be added/changed to make this?

I am pretty sure, this class has to use Graphics.lineTo() to draw each plot, so basically it would need to "get" the current alphaField value somehow, and apply a Graphics.lineStyle() with the correct alpha before drawing each line.

Thanks!!

---

**UPDATE**

I have gotten much closer to my answer.

When I extend LineRenderer I override updateDisplayList() which calls GraphicsUtilities.drawPolyLine()

I extend GraphicsUtilities and override the method drawPolyLine() as this is where the line is actually drawn.

I can call lineStyle() in here and change the alpha of the line...

**I still have 1 thing I cannot figure out, from within the drawPolyLine() method how can I access that data that dictates what the alpha should be?**

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Flex SDK 4.0, but I believe it'll work on 3.4 as well.

Used ArrayCollection instead of XML, because it wasn't the tsimus.

```
<mx:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo" >

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        import mx.charts.ChartItem;
        import mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.graphics.IFill;
        import mx.graphics.SolidColor;
        import mx.graphics.Stroke;

        import st.model.ViewModelLocator;

        [Bindable]
        private var modelLocator:st.model.ViewModelLocator = ViewModelLocator.getInstance() ;

        [Bindable]
        public var dp :ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            { test:0.1,alpha: 1 },
            { test:0.2,alpha: 0.5 },
            { test:0.3,alpha: 0.75 },
            { test:0.4,alpha: 0.25 },
            { test:0.5,alpha: 0.5 }
        ]);

        private function myFillFunction(element:ChartItem, index:Number):IFill {
            return new SolidColor(0x6699FF,Number(element.item.alpha));
        }
    ]]></fx:Script>

    <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{dp}">
        <mx:series>
            <mx:LineSeries lineStroke="{new Stroke(0x6699FF,4,0.1)}" width="100" height="100" yField="test" fillFunction="{myFillFunction}" itemRenderer="{new ClassFactory(mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer)}" />
        </mx:series>
    </mx:ColumnChart>

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks, this changes the joints, I am trying to change the actually lines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a custom item renderer?

```
<mx:LineSeries>
  <mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
      <mx:BoxItemRenderer scaleX="1" scaleY="1" alpha="{data.alpha}"/>
    </mx:Component>
  </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:LineSeries>
```

This is just a quick example, but I think the itemRenderer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In `drawPolyLine` function you will get `pts:Array`. This is an array of the specific SeriesItem.
For Line series you will get an array of `LineSeriesItem` objects. So if you want to get your x&y axis values. you just access the `xValue` or `yValue` property of a `LineSeriesItem`. like this: `pts[0].xValue` or `pts[0].yValue`

---

```
public static function drawPolyLine(g:Graphics, pts:Array,
                                     start:int, end:int,
                                     hProp:String, vProp:String,
                                     stroke:IStroke, form:Object,
                                     moveToStart:Boolean = true):void
```